# Notificações do PagSeguro: Não foi possível reenviar a notificação

Tags: php

Antes de realizar esta pergunta, li todas as perguntas já existentes sobre "pagseguro notificações".

No SANDBOX, não estou recebendo notificações das transações.

Estou testando em um domínio válido, hospedado em uma VM, Linux Ubuntu 14.04,  na locaweb.

Minha url de notificação possui certificado SSL, Versão 3, emitido por "COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA", com algoritmo "Criptografia PKCS #1 SHA-256 com RSA".

Coloquei para escrever no **LOG de erros do APACHE**: "NOTIFICACAO ACIONADA!", logo na primeira linha do meu arquivo de notificações, em PHP, que deveria ser chamado chamado, a cada notificação de alteração de Status de transação, conforme trecho de código abaixo.

```
<?php
error_log('NOTIFICACAO ACIONADA!');
$http_origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'];

$array_origens_permitidas[] = 'https://pagseguro.uol.com.br';
$array_origens_permitidas[] = 'https://ws.pagseguro.uol.com.br';
$array_origens_permitidas[] = 'https://stc.pagseguro.uol.com.br';
$array_origens_permitidas[] = 'https://sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br';
$array_origens_permitidas[] = 'https://ws.sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br';
$array_origens_permitidas[] = 'https://stc.sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br';

if (in_array($http_origin, $array_origens_permitidas)){  
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $http_origin");
}
```

Também já tentei utilizar:

```
$request_headers        = apache_request_headers();
$http_origin            = $request_headers['Origin'];
```

No lugar de:

```
$http_origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'];
```

Seguem abaixo, os módulos instalados no apache, listados com `print_r(apache_get_modules());`

> ```
> Array (
> [0] => core
> [1] => mod_so
> [2] => mod_watchdog
> [3] => http_core
> [4] => mod_log_config
> [5] => mod_logio
> [6] => mod_version
> [7] => mod_unixd
> [8] => mod_access_compat
> [9] => mod_alias
> [10] => mod_auth_basic
> [11] => mod_authn_core
> [12] => mod_authn_file
> [13] => mod_authz_core
> [14] => mod_authz_host
> [15] => mod_authz_user
> [16] => mod_autoindex
> [17] => mod_cache
> [18] => mod_deflate
> [19] => mod_dir
> [20] => mod_env
> [21] => mod_expires
> [22] => mod_file_cache
> [23] => mod_filter
> [24] => mod_headers
> [25] => mod_mime
> [26] => prefork
> [27] => mod_negotiation
> [28] => mod_php5
> [29] => mod_setenvif
> [30] => mod_socache_shmcb
> [31] => mod_ssl
> [32] => mod_status )
> ```

Ao clicar no botão "Reenviar notificação", aparece o erro: "Não foi possível reenviar a notificação." e NADA é escrito no log do APACHE.

Ao clicar em "Ver log" aparece a URL da notificação e a mensagem: "A notificacao nao foi enviada. Verifique a URL de notificacao e faca uma nova transacao." e NADA é escrito no log do APACHE.

Ao copiar e colar a URL da notificação em um browser, aparece no log do APACHE a mensagem: "NOTIFICACAO ACIONADA!".

A url de notificação está sendo definida através da tela de configuração do SANDBOX, na área "Vendedor de Testes", campo: "Definir URL para receber as notificações:".

Além disso, envio a url de notificação também no POST de pagamento, via cURL, como "notificationURL".

Nenhum registro de bloqueio no firewall (IPTABLES).

Uma vez que, o nada é registrado no log do APACHE ao clicar no botão "Reenviar notificação", mas quando digito a URL diretamente no BROWSER o acesso é registrado no LOG do APACHE.

**Estranho que:**
Ao clicar em "**Reenviar notificação local**", a notificação é enviada e tudo funciona corretamente. Estando os dados hospedados em um servidor WEB, com IP público e URL válida.

Parece que por algum motivo o PAGSEGURO não está enviando as notificações para a minha url de notificação.

Alguém teria alguma ideia do que pode estar acontecendo? O que posso ter feito errado? O que posso ter esquecido de fazer?

Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda!

Comment: Esta testando no localhost?

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção... estou testando em um domínio válido, hospedado em uma VM, Linux Ubuntu 14.04,  na locaweb.

Comment: Tive esse problema quando estava no localhost, ai era o navegador bloqueando alguns scripts, ai aparecia um icone no canto superior direito no caso do Chrome. Mas no servidor on-line não tive esse problema

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Após muita pesquisa e testes, descobri que apesar do [PagSeguro](https://pagseguro.uol.com.br/) informar que aceita o certificado TLS v1.1, na verdade ele só aceita o TLS v1.0.

Sendo que para isso, na configuração do SITE no Apache, na linha da configuração `SSLProtocol` deve ser adicionada a configuração `+TLSV1.0`, que dá habilita o protocolo TLS versão 1.0.

Importante lembrar que o protocolo TLS nas versões 1.0 e 1.1 já está defasado e com falhas de segurança, portanto, deve ser usado com cautela.

Comment: O PagSeguro também tem problemas com certificados SNI, como os usados pelo Cloudflare e Let's Encrypt. Pelo menos até algum tempo atrás tinha.

Answer (score 0):

Vou colocar meu código de recepção da notificação aqui, não sei como está o seu... Mas como o meu esta funcionando gravando no banco, talvez isso pode te ajudar. Ai comenta aqui qualquer dúvida. Nesse código abaixo, é o arquivo que está configurado no pagseguro para receber as notificações, no caso o nofiticacao.php. Ele recebe a notificação salva no banco o código e o status da transação. Espero poder ajudar...
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
  <?php
 include_once("sistema/config.php");

     header("access-control-allow-origin: https://sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br");
     if (count($_POST)>0) {

               $email = "meu email";
               $token = " meu token";
               $notificationCode = $_POST['notificationCode'];
               $url = "https://ws.sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v3/transactions/notifications/".$notificationCode."?email=".$email."&token=".$token;

               $curl = curl_init($url);
               curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
               curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
               $response = curl_exec($curl);
               $http = curl_getinfo($curl);

               if($response == 'Unauthorized'){
                        print_r($response);
                        exit;
               }
               curl_close($curl);
               $response= simplexml_load_string($response);

               if(count($response -> error) > 0){
                        print_r($response);
                        exit;
               }

       $conexao=Conecta();
            $preparado=$conexao->prepare("INSERT hf_status_faturas(id_fatura,idStatus) VALUES(?,?)");
$preparado->execute(array($response->code,$response->status));

     }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu estava com o mesmo problema.
Resolveu quando eu removi a `URL de Notificação` na hora de gerar a URL do pagamento. Então eu alterei a URL para Notificação de transações dentro da interface do Sandbox PagSeguro, no menu PERFIS DE INTEGRAÇÃO. Desse jeito comecei a ser notificado quando alterava o status:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]