# Não recebo POST sandbox na minha URL de notificações do PagSeguro (PHP)

Tags: php

Na TOTAL ausência de qualquer retorno na comunidade de dev do pagseguro tô aqui pra ver se alguma boa alma tem alguma sugestão. Não consigo receber as notificações enviadas pelo Sandbox do pagseguro, na verdade o sandbox (aparentemente) nem envia. Não existem tentativas de requisições na minha URL pelos logs do meu servidor.

Existe, claro, a possibilidade de o problema ser o sandbox. Mas gostaria de eliminar todos os possíveis problemas pra ter certeza.

Inserindo o código da notificação por GET ou fazendo o teste do POST pelo ARC o script roda direitinho. É esse:

```
<?php
header("access-control-allow-origin: https://sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br");

$notificationCode = preg_replace('/[^[:alnum:]-]/','',$_GET["notificationCode"]);

$data = array(
    'email' => ' ',
    'token' => ' '
);

$data = http_build_query($data);

$url = 'https://ws.sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v3/transactions/notifications/'.$notificationCode.'?'.$data;

$curl = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);

$retorno = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

$retorno = simplexml_load_string($retorno);

$codigoTransacao = $retorno->code;

$fp = fopen("logNotifications.txt", "a");
$escreve = fwrite($fp, "\n CÓDIGO DA TRANSAÇÃO PRA TESTE: {$codigoTransacao}");
fclose($fp);

?>
```

Já tentei mudar os parâmetros do CURL removendo o CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION e CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, mudando o CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER pra false... nada resolve.

Li que o Sandbox opera somente em SSL e TLS versão 1.2, minha URL de notificação é https:// e os dados do meu server são:

```
OS: Linux
PHP version: 5.6.36
curl version: 7.59.0
SSL version: OpenSSL/1.0.2o
SSL version number: 0
OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER: 100020ff
TLS test (default): TLS 1.2
TLS test (TLS_v1): TLS 1.2
TLS test (TLS_v1_2): TLS 1.2
```

Já tentei mandando a url de notificação durante a compra para o pagseguro por código, e sem mandar. A url de notificação está configurada nos perfis de integração do sandbox tanto no vendedor quanto na aplicação e não tem jeito. O retorno é sempre esse quando tento enviar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se eu limpo o campo de notificação aí mesmo nos detalhes de transação, ele gera um log informando que a URL de notificação é inválida. Isso que me fez questionar se existe algum problema com a minha URL de recebimento.

Já testei pra ver se havia algum bloqueio no servidor referente a URL do pagseguro, nada.

```
# ping ws.sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br
PING ws.sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br (186.234.51.18) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 186.234.51.18 (186.234.51.18): icmp_seq=1 ttl=245 time=2.26 ms
64 bytes from 186.234.51.18 (186.234.51.18): icmp_seq=2 ttl=245 time=1.34 ms
^C
--- ws.sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.349/1.806/2.263/0.457 ms
```

Acredito que não é problema de porta também pq o server opera em 80 e 443(https) e pela documentação do pagseguro, é isso mesmo.

Já tentei também o sugerido [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/170299/notifica%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-pagseguro-n%C3%A3o-foi-poss%C3%ADvel-reenviar-a-notifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o) mas o tópico é antigo e segundo links da comunidade do Pagseguro, agora é utilizado TLS 1.2. Por desencargo de consciência também tentei forçar no CURL TLS 1.0 e 1.1: nada.

**Tem algo que eu estou deixando passar?**

Comment: Qual o endereço da sua URL de recebimento?

Comment: https:// [...].com.br/pagseguro/recebe-notificacoes.php

Answer (score 2):

Caso possa ajudar alguém um dia, montei um trecho de código que para mim funcionou. Segue abaixo.

```
if(isset($_POST)){
   $notificationCode=$_POST["notificationCode"];
   $notificationType=$_POST["notificationType"];
   $email="e-mail da conta Pagseguro";
   $token="token da sandbox";

   $requisicao="https://ws.sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/transactions/notifications/".$notificationCode."?email=".$email."&token=".$token;

   $curl=curl_init($requisicao);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   $response=curl_exec($curl);
   curl_close($curl);
   if($response=='Unauthorized'){
     error_log((string)$response);
   }else{
     $response=simplexml_load_string($response);
     if(count($response->error)>0){
        error_log((string)$response);
     }else{
        error_log($response->code);
        error_log($response->status);
     }
}}
```